# How to search "Folder" in folder and subfolder with specific level

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Folder structure:

```
c:\rootfolder\C1
c:\rootfolder\C1\C1
'   this is the folder need to be search at third level
c:\rootfolder\C1\C1\C2
c:\rootfolder\C1\C1\C2\C3
```

```
Call SearchFolder("C1")
'    return:
c:\rootfolder\C1\C1\
```

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim Files = SearchFolder("X:\JOBS\",  & "-" & Me.txtIIGNumber.Text).Distinct.ToList
    For Each icount As String In Files
        Debug.Print(icount.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Function SearchFolder(ByVal RootFolder As String, FindFolder As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim ReturnedData As New List(Of String)
    Dim FolderStack As New Stack(Of String)
    FolderStack.Push(RootFolder)

    Do While FolderStack.Count > 0
        Dim ThisFolder As String = FolderStack.Pop.ToString
        Try
            For Each SubFolder In GetDirectories(ThisFolder)
                FolderStack.Push(SubFolder)
                ReturnedData.AddRange(GetDirectories(ThisFolder, FindFolder))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Loop

    Return ReturnedData          

End Function
```

I am looking for a piece of correction where I can search for a specific folder within all subfolders at a specific level.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Can you post your code for SearchFolder?  [This may be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.directoryexists?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: SO is not a site where you tell us the result you want and we write the code for you. You need to put some thought into the problem first. As with all problems, start by forgetting programming and concentrating on logic. If you had to do this manually, what would you do? Could you do it? Of course you could. Now, what if you had to explain how to do it to someone else? What steps would you tell them to perform? If you haven't thought about that then you haven't tried to solve this problem. Once you understand the steps, formalise them into an algorithm and then implement that in code.

Comment: Once you get to the implementation stage, if what you try doesn't work, THEN you have a question worthy of asking here. You would explain what you're trying to achieve, how your trying to achieve it and exactly what happens when you try.

Comment: sorry about that. I was only looking for a hint like the first comment. thanks

Comment: I see that you have a parameter `FindFolder As String` which I guess is the directory name that you want to match, but in what way do you want it to be at a "specific level"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it needs is some way of measuring the directory depth, and some way of getting a subdirectory with a name matching the desired one.

Then you can stop searching further once the required depth is reached.

Something like:

```vb
Function DirectoryDepth(d As String) As Integer
    Dim dirCount = If(d.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), 0, 1)
    Dim root = Path.GetPathRoot(d)
    Dim dirsToCount = d.Substring(root.Length)
    Return dirCount + dirsToCount.Count(Function(c) c = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)

End Function

Function MatchingDirectory(baseDir As String, dirName As String) As String
    Return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(baseDir).
                    FirstOrDefault(Function(d) (New DirectoryInfo(d)).Name.Equals(dirName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))

End Function

Function GetNamedSubdirectories(ByVal rootDirectory As String, findDirectory As String, depth As Integer) As List(Of String)

    Dim foundDirs As New List(Of String)
    Dim dirStack As New Stack(Of String)
    dirStack.Push(rootDirectory)

    Do While dirStack.Count > 0
        Dim thisDir = dirStack.Pop()

        If DirectoryDepth(thisDir) = depth - 1 Then
            Dim matchingDir = MatchingDirectory(thisDir, findDirectory)
            If matchingDir <> "" Then foundDirs.Add(matchingDir)
        Else

            For Each subDir In Directory.EnumerateDirectories(thisDir)

                If DirectoryDepth(subDir) < depth - 1 Then
                    dirStack.Push(subDir)
                End If

                If DirectoryDepth(subDir) = depth - 1 Then
                    Dim matchingDir = MatchingDirectory(subDir, findDirectory)
                    If matchingDir <> "" Then foundDirs.Add(matchingDir)
                End If

            Next

        End If

    Loop

    Return foundDirs

End Function
```

Given:

```
C:\TEMP\C1
├───C1
│   └───C3
├───C2
│   └───C3
└───C3
    └───C3
```

The output from:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, GetNamedSubdirectories("C:\temp", "C3", 4)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, GetNamedSubdirectories("C:\temp", "C2", 3)))
```

is:

```
C:\temp\C1\C1\C3
C:\temp\C1\C2\C3
C:\temp\C1\C3\C3
C:\temp\C1\C2
```